# Lua function returning error after false "if statement"

Tags: lua, coronasdk, solar2d

I have a function to move a point over to different positions. I have a *positions* table containing all the Xs and Ys of each position, a position counter (*posCounter*) do keep track of where the point is and a *maxPos*, which is pretty much the lenght of the table *positions*.
In this code snippet, everything after `if posCounter <= maxPos then` shouldn't run if the posCounter variable is greater than 3, but **I still get an error** for exceeding the table's limit.

```
local maxPos = 3
local posCounter = 1
local function movePointToNext( event )
    if posCounter <= maxPos then
        posCounter = posCounter + 1
        transition.to( pointOnMap, { x = positions[posCounter].x, y = positions[posCounter].y } )
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if posCounter <= maxPos then
        posCounter = posCounter + 1
```

What happens if posCounter == maxPos? Your if executes, then you **increment it**, so it is too big (equal to maxPos + 1), and then you try to index with it, thus giving you an error.

You either want to change your if to stop at posCounter == maxPos - 1, so that after incrementing it still is correct; or you want to move your increment **after** indexing with it (depending on what is the intended behaviour of your code).

### option 1

```
local maxPos = 3
local posCounter = 1
local function movePointToNext( event )
    if posCounter < maxPos then
        posCounter = posCounter + 1
        transition.to( pointOnMap, { 
            x = positions[posCounter].x, 
            y = positions[posCounter].y } )
    end
end
```

### option 2

```
local maxPos = 3
local posCounter = 1
local function movePointToNext( event )
    if posCounter <= maxPos then
        transition.to( pointOnMap, { 
            x = positions[posCounter].x, 
            y = positions[posCounter].y } )
        posCounter = posCounter + 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, realized now how lame of a mistake it was. I'm going to use the first one as I still need it to move to the next, and therefore require for the counter to increment before the movement is made. Thanks again.